# morph and/or blend multiples in geoNodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: screen_shot]

I am using Blender 3,5Beta--cannot figure out how to add in a third object for blending like the two in the screenshot (all the same number of vertices).Any help/suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: why don't you just add another mix node after your mix node and do another join + object info + sample index?

Comment: THANKS, yes, did that! though i am trying to find a way for 1 "slider" or factor to control combos of all 3 meshes..

Comment: This could work with simple geometries but complex meshes would produce very jumbled results, no? If simple geometries is enough for you, detach this Set Position from where it currently is, link one of your objects to it, and then link *that* to Join Geometry. Your factor will control this third, new blend between them. Is that what you're after?

Comment: thanks! yes, just fiddling around with the math because first mix is not equivalent to second: first the mix of mesh 1 + 2, then the result gets added to 3rd mesh so its never .33-.33-.33.

Comment: This link is to a thread where there is a geometry solution. The file to download is called wave3 and it was created by sozap. It's collection based so the index order will be from the  top of the collecrion to the bottom . Enjoy and please reward him with a like . https://blenderartists.org/t/crashing-wave-rig/1469696/25?u=benny7770